# When deploying, I get the error "SocialPersona.ParentId Entity 'SocialPersona' not found."

Tags: deployment

I am currently deploying to clone an org from another org, and so I've downloaded the entire metadata set, and started deploying to a new org.

I get many errors, most of which revolve around the object "SocialPersonna".
Here is a log of those errors:

```
SocialPersona.ExternalId    Custom Field    34  13  An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 641024822-10433 (-1547453179)  
SocialPersona.Name  Custom Field    40  13  An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 641024822-10435 (-1547453179)
SocialPersona.ParentId  Custom Field    43  13  Entity 'SocialPersona' not found.  
SocialPersona.ProfileUrl    Custom Field    47  13  An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 641024822-10436 (-1547453179)  
SocialPersona.Provider  Custom Field    50  13  An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 641024822-10437 (-1547453179)  
SocialPersona.SourceApp Custom Field    53  13  An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 641024822-10438 (-1547453179)
```

As you can see, these errors are very generic, and do not tell of what is going wrong. Could somebody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3):

Some Salesforce features are optional in orgs. You have a feature turned on in the source org and have components that depend on that feature in the extracted metadata. When you try do deploy those components into an org that does not have the feature you get the sort of errors you are seeing.

The quick fix is to turn the feature on in the destination org. (Think the feature you are using may be part of [Radian6](https://www.marketingcloud.com/products/social-media-marketing/radian6/)). The harder fix is to eliminate the dependency in the metadata of the source org.

Comment: I'm not familiar, how would one do that? A quick google and the closest thing that I could find is a petition to allow this sort of action to happen, which leads me to believe that its not possible.

Comment: @tuskiomi The quick fix or the harder fix?

Comment: Sorry, the quick fix

Comment: @tuskiomi You will have to ask your colleagues for how the feature got turned on or Google to find out: a payment to Salesforce may be involved.

Comment: AFAIK, both the orgs are free dev orgs, but I may be wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @tuskiomi Then it may just be a switch in the destination org that you need to turn on.